# How to perform a reverse DNS lookup in Python?

Tags: python, shared-hosting, reverse-lookup

Is there any way to do a reverse lookup using python, to check the list of websites sharing the same IP address in a shared hosting?

[Some web sites](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/) offer a tool for this purpose .

Comment: This is not possible with reverse DNS. You need a database that matches hostnames to IP addresses and then search by IP address. Reverse DNS searches in the PTR records. Most domains only have one, and it's not necessarily the hosted domain. Per example, one of `google.com` A record points to `74.125.228.97`, but the reverse DNS entry for that IP is `iad23s08-in-f1.1e100.net`.

Comment: I think I should use python with an another API to do this .

Answer (score 13):

## DNSPython

Technically, you can use [DNSPython](http://www.dnspython.org/) to do a reverse lookup.

Pip install it

```
$ pip install dnspython
```

Then do your reverse query:

```
>>> from dns import resolver
>>> from dns import reversename
>>> addr = reversename.from_address("74.125.227.114")
>>> resolver.query(addr, "PTR")[0]
<DNS IN PTR rdata: dfw06s16-in-f18.1e100.net.>
```

## `socket.gethostbyaddr`

You can also use `socket.gethostbyaddr`

```
>>> import socket
>>> name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr('192.30.252.130')
>>> name
'ip1c-lb3-prd.iad.github.com'
```

*Note that you'll want to check for a `socket.herror` Exception when using `gethostbyaddr`.*

## Problems with doing a reverse lookup

As for finding out what sites are hosted on a particular IP, this may not lend the best results in a shared hosting environment. It will likely tell you about the provider, not the site:

```
14:38:43 ~/code/tmp$ ping mozeyondown.com
PING mozeyondown.com (173.203.99.161): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.203.99.161: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=40.924 ms
```

Let's look up that address now

```
14:38:54 ~/code/tmp$ dig +noall +answer -x 173.203.99.161
161.99.203.173.in-addr.arpa. 86053 IN   PTR 173-203-99-161.static.cloud-ips.com.
```

Looking it up via Python

```
>>> import socket
>>> name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr('173.203.99.161')
>>> name
'173-203-99-161.static.cloud-ips.com'
```

Same goes for using DNSPython.

Comment: I think asking for a tool to get a list of all domains hosted in 1 shared hosting IP: For exp something like bing: https://www.bing.com/search?q=IP:87.98.235.184

And/Or other paid services like : 1. yougetsignal tools web-sites-on-web-server 2. hackertarget reverse-ip-lookup